# Appending the first letter of each word to the end

Tags: ruby

For each word, I am trying to move the first letter of the word to the end of the word. For example,

- `"this is an example"` ----> `"hist si na xamplee"`.

I achieved this with one word, for example,

```
x = "hello"
x << x.split("").shift # => "elloh"
```

Comment: Your code returns `"helloh"`, not `"elloh"`.

Comment: Would "o'clock" become "'clocko"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'this is an example'.split.map { |word| word.chars.rotate.join }.join(' ')
#=> "hist si na xamplee"
```

References:

- [String#`chars`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-chars)
- [Array#`rotate`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-rotate)

Answer (score 6):

```
"this is an example".gsub(/(\S)(\S+)/, '\2\1')
# => "hist si na xamplee"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times".
   gsub(/[\p{Alpha}']+/) {  |s| s[1..-1]<<s[0]}
   #=> "tI asw het estb fo imest, ti asw het orstw fo imest"
```